# Vision API not getting Text recognised properly in iOS 17.0 but works on older version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, vision-api

I am trying to scan some text from document. Everything was working before iOS 17.0. But after iOS update, I am not able to get proper results. Most of the times I got a single string in multiple breakup. The scan result is 30% success that is 100% with older iOS versions.
I have used Apple's `Vision API` for the same. Let me know if anyone else facing the same issue?
Any help will be appreciated.

Check the code snippet below for Text Recogniser:

```
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        completionHandler(.failure(error!))
        return
    }

    let visionResults = request.results as! [VNRecognizedTextObservation]

    let result: [TextRecognizerResult] = visionResults.map {
        .init(results: $0.topCandidates(10).map { $0.string }, boundingRect: $0.boundingBox)
    }

    completionHandler(.success(result))
}

if let regionOfInterest = regionOfInterest {
    request.regionOfInterest = regionOfInterest
}
if let minimumTextHeight = minimumTextHeight {
    request.minimumTextHeight = minimumTextHeight
}
request.recognitionLevel = recognitionLevel == .fast ? .fast : .accurate
request.usesLanguageCorrection = false

let imageRequestHandler: VNImageRequestHandler
switch scanningImage {
case .cgImage(let image):
    imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
case .pixelBuffer(let pixelBuffer):
    imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        completionHandler(.failure(error))
    }
}
```